# TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchField' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchField' of null
>   App.render

[image: entire error report rest of project files in comments]

Comment: How did you define `state`?

Comment: thats the file inwhich the error happen new to react so apologize if it was stupid error: https://github.com/ahmedabdo97/robofriends/blob/master/src/containers/App.js

Comment: enclose the `return` statement of `render` function of `App.js` in `()` and try. sometimes it make mess.

Comment: thanks fixed seems its props dependent so i done this.props instead of this.state and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchField' of null

Means the compiler doesn't found a `state` in your component.

And you want to retrieve this values from `redux` so you've to use
`this.props` instead of `this.state`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, all props you're trying to use comes from store (via mapStateToProps), so instead of

```
const { searchField, onSearchChange, robots, isPending } = this.state;
```

You should do

```
const { searchField, onSearchChange, robots, isPending } = this.props;
```

Also, if you use state in render, don't forget to initialize state in component or constructor:

```
// if your state doesn't depend on props    
class App extends Component {
         state = {
           isLoading: false
         }
    ....



//if your state depends on props(rare case but sometimes useful)

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      const {isLoading} = props;
      this.state = {
         isLoading
      }
    }
....
```